# Flutter 2.0 Navigator w/ Provider Gives Null Value Errors when Popping

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently having some data race bugs when using the Flutter 2.0 Navigator API.  My store is implemented with MobX and passed down via `Provider`.  After that, I pull an `Observer` over the global store and then re-update the `Navigator` (for the routes) every time my global store updates.  However, everything works fine until I hit the top back arrow on the `WinnerPage`.  It shows the following error on the screen and flashes back to being fine instantly later:

```
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was WinnerView
```

Therefore, to try and debug further, I learned that the value of `winner` is `null` for an instant (from `onPopPage` in `Navigator`) when pressing the back button, which pops the state.  Does anyone know if there is a fix to this problem?  Here is all of my code:

### Store

```dart
class GlobalStore extends Store {
  @observable
  String? winner;

  @action
  void setWinner(String? newWinner) => winner = newWinner;
}
```

### App Setup

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "MyApp",
      home: Provider<GlobalStore>(
        create: (_) => GlobalStore(),
        child: Observer(builder: (context) {
          final store = Provider.of<GlobalStore>(context);
          return Navigator(
            pages: [
              FooPage(),
              if (store.winner != null)
                WinnerPage()
            ],
            onPopPage: (route, result) {
              if (!route.didPop(result)) {
                return false;
              }

              store.setWinner(null);

              return true;
            }
          );
        }),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

### Foo Page (default)

```dart
class FooPage extends Page {
  const FooPage() : super(key: const ValueKey('Foo Page'));

  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: this, builder: (BuildContext context) => FooView());
  }
}

class FooView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final store = Provider.of<GlobalStore>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        child: const Text('Hello, world!'),
        onPressed: () {
          store.setWinner("You!");
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

### Winner Page

```dart
class WinnerPage extends Page {
  const WinnerPage() : super(key: const ValueKey('Winner Page'));

  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: this, builder: (BuildContext context) => WinnerView());
  }
}

class WinnerView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final store = Provider.of<GlobalStore>(context);
    final winner = store.winner!; // error here!
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(children: [Text('${winner} is the winner!')]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this myself, although I cannot find a complete explanation for why the problem was happening so if anyone else has a better answer please write it.  Anyways, It looks like for some reason my way of extending `Page` was not working correctly.  Therefore, I changed each of my `Navigator.pages` to look like this:

```dart
[
  // note: I am using the stateless widget views not pages
  MaterialPage(child: const FooView(), key: const ValueKey("FooPage")),
  if (store.winner != null)
    MaterialPage(child: const WinnerView(), key: const ValueKey("WinnerPage"))
]
```

I also have a hunch that the problem was that I was only extending `Page`, not `MaterialPage`, which may not have the same behavior.  However, I still don't know why it wasn't working the other way after ~1 hr of searching.